# RDFa Snippet Generator from GoodRelations

Tags: microformats, rdfa, rich-snippets

I've created a RDFa snippet to use on a client's website using the GoodRelations tool. The generated code creates the tags as expected, but there's no text between the divs, for instance:

```
<div typeof="vcard:Address">
    <div property="vcard:locality" content="Yorba Linda"></div>
</div>
```

I'm assuming that this is OK, and that I am expected to put descriptive text for humans between the 'locality' divs without any adverse effects (in relation to SEO.) Correct?

Comment: I seriously hope you're right but due to another answer from Google yesterday I still have doubts. They keep saying: "We will not mark up hidden content."

Answer (score 1):

As William says: In most cases, is is impractical to reuse visible content for publishing meta-data, because they differ in sequence or structure. In that case, it is better to put all meta-data in a single block of <div> elements without visible content. This is called "RDFa in Snippet Style", see

- http://www.ebusiness-unibw.org/tools/rdf2rdfa/
- Hepp, Martin; García, Roberto; Radinger, Andreas: RDF2RDFa: Turning RDF into Snippets for Copy-and-Paste, Technical Report TR-2009-01, 2009., PDF at http://www.heppnetz.de/files/RDF2RDFa-TR.pdf

Google is consuming such markup, despite a general preference for marking up visible content. Many big shops are using this approach with good results, e.g. http://www.rachaelraystore.com/Product/detail/Rachael-Ray-Stoneware-2-pc-Bubble-Brown-Baker-Set-Eggplant/316398

So if you can integrate the visible content and the RDFa constructs, then use

```
<div typeof="vcard:Address">
    <div property="vcard:locality">Yorba Linda</div>
</div>
```

If you cannot, then use

```
<div typeof="vcard:Address">
    <div property="vcard:locality" content="Yorba Linda"></div>
</div>
...
<div>
    <div>Yorba Linda</div>
</div>
```

But the divs with invisible content must be close to the visible content and be placed better before than after the visible markup.

Answer (score 0):

From and RDFa point of view, it is fine (I am assuming you are using bracers because you don't know how to escape greater than / less than characters).

The only thing you need to think about is how adding this fragment of HTML to your HTML document, will affect the rendering. Based on the fact that you are using the content attribute, this fragment is destined to remain hidden. So yo should think about this in relation to the CSS architecture. My advice would be to create a specific CSS class that is for annotations.

Having spoken to the author of Good Relations, his advice would be to put this fragment before any other HTML element in the body of your document. Generally, the Rich Snippets team indicate that they ignore hidden RDFa, but it doesn't actually matter and really in the long run it enables the publishing of RDF to anyone (not only Google) who wants to consume it.

Comment: Thank you William. Actually I did try to escape with '\', but perhaps because of quirks in my browser(?) the lt and gt brackets would not show in the message preview.